# I would like to link values of one dictionary to keys in another

Tags: dictionary, sorteddictionary

I have two .csv files containing information which I would like to link. I read each .csv file into a dictionary and named it as follows:

```
               Key      Value              
Dictionary1 = {Complex, Protein}    
Dictionary2 = {Protein, Absorbance}
```

I would like to be able to link the proteins from `Dictionary1` to `Dictionary2` so the end result would be if I were to call a complex in `Dictionary1` it would give me the absorbances associated with all the proteins in `Dictionary2`.

*Perhaps I have taken the wrong approach putting both the data sets into dictionaries...*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value resulting from the lookup in the first as the key for the second. Of course, assuming that the data is immutable.

Python:

```
dict1 = {'Complex': 'Protein'}
dict2 = {'Protein': 'Absorbance'}

dict2[dict1['Complex']] # 'Absorbance'
```